# google.setOnLoadCallback with parameter inside jquery ajax success function

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

Sample code:
Both of these seem to work ok, to display a message:

```
google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
...
$(document).ready(function () {

  google.setOnLoadCallback(function () {
    alert('from inside ready 1');
  });
});

$(document).ready(function () {

  google.setOnLoadCallback(alert('from inside ready 2'));
});
```

Note: I'm using alert(..) just for debugging purposes - my real code draws charts. Now, I want to use these techniques inside $.ajax e.g. :

```
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    ... 
    success: function (result) {
      if (result.d) {

        $(document).ready(function () {
          alert('sucess');

          // option 1
          google.setOnLoadCallback(function () {
            alert('from inside ready 3');
          });

          // option 2
          // google.setOnLoadCallback(alert('from inside ready 4'));
        });
```

Now, on ajax success, I can see "sucess" shown, but option 1 doesn't seem to work. i.e. I don't see "from inside ready 3". If I enable the code at option 2, and comment out the code for option 1, I DO see "from inside ready 4".

So it seems that option 2 works, but not option 1, from a jquery ajax call. Can anyone shed some light? Is option 2 100% safe to use? It seems to work, but all the examples I've seen seem to use option 1.

Comment: `google.setOnLoadCallback(alert('from inside ready 2'));` is `alert`ing *immediately*, not when `google` loads. Definitely not safe to use.

Comment: Option 2 is not valid for what you're trying to do as it fires immediately and sets the return value of the function you call (`alert()` in this case) as the value returned to the function. I'm not familiar with this Google library, but I would surmise that option 1 most likely doesn't work as you set an 'onload' callback, yet the load event fired a long time ago, before your AJAX success handler is called. I'd check the Google docs to find another suitable method.

Comment: You might use `Promise.all`, with one promise resolving when google loads, and another resolving when the ajax request comes back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first, you're using the old version of google charts,
the `jsapi` library should no longer be used,
see the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes)...

> The version of Google Charts that remains available via the `jsapi` loader is no longer being updated consistently. Please use the new gstatic `loader.js` from now on.

old: `<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>`

current: `<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>`

this will only change the load statement...

from...

```
google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
```

to...

```
google.charts.load("current", { packages: ["corechart"] });
```

---

next, you don't need to use the callback every time you need to draw a chart,
it only needs to be used once, to ensure google charts has been loaded.

and there are several ways to use the callback,
you can use the updated `setOnLoadCallback` function.

```
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
```

or you can place the callback directly in the `load` statement.

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

or what I prefer, the promise it returns. (google includes a promise polyfill for IE)

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(drawChart);
```

---

now to the question at hand,
google's `load` statement will wait for the document to load by default,
so you can use `google.charts.load` in place of `$(document).ready`

recommend loading google first, then using ajax to get data, then draw your charts.

something similar to the following setup...

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {

  // get data for chart 1
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    ...
  }).done(function (result) {

    drawChart1(result.d);

  }).fail(function (jqXHR, status, errorThrown) {
    console.log(errorThrown);
  });

  // get data for chart 2
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    ...
  }).done(function (result) {

    drawChart2(result.d);

  }).fail(function (jqXHR, status, errorThrown) {
    console.log(errorThrown);
  });

});

function drawChart1(chartData) {
  ...
}

function drawChart2(chartData) {
  ...
}
```