# How to Promise chain multiple google.charts.setOnLoadCallback's?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, promise, google-visualization

I am using Google's Firestore to obtain data and then using `google.charts.setOnLoadCallback` to plot the data. The first drawing function `draw1` calls for the data, and then the other `draw2` and `draw2` should reuse the same data.

I tried Promise chaining the three `google.charts.setOnLoadCallback` calls, in order to assure that the second and third calls get executed after the first in order to be sure I have the data passed through. The console logs should show 1, 2, 3, 4 as the order of execution, but instead, I get back 3, 4, 1, 2 - and the Step 3 and 4 have undefined data being passed to them - as the first two Promises have not finished running and the data does not exist yet.

Is it possible to daisy chain `google.charts.setOnLoadCallback` Promises? See code example below:

```
function initFirebase() {
    // Initialize Cloud Firestore through Firebase
    firebase.initializeApp({
        apiKey: "MyKey",
        authDomain: "MyDomain",
        projectId: "MyProject",
    });
    return firebase.firestore();
}

const getFirebaseData = db => {
    var doc_ref = db.collection('collection').doc('doc'); 
    var queryLimit = doc_ref.orderBy("field1", "desc").limit(10);
    var field1Arr = [];
    var field2Arr = [];

    return queryLimit.get()
        .then(querySnapshot => {
            querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
                var data = doc.data();
                field1Arr.push(data.field1);
                field2Arr.push(data.field2);
            });
            
            dataArr.push(field1Arr, field2Arr);
            console.log("#1: Returning Data Array from Firebase", dataArr);
            return dataArr; 
       });
}

function draw1() {
    var db = initFirebase();
    getFirebaseData(db).then(data => {
        console.log("#2: Draw 1 Data: ", data);
        return data;
    }); 
}
        
function draw2(data) {
    console.log("#3: Draw 2 Data: ", data);
    return data;
}

function draw3(data) {
    console.log("#4: Draw 3 data: ", data);
    return data;
}


google.charts.load('current', {
    packages: ['corechart', 'line']
});
        
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(draw1)
    .then(function(data) {
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(draw2(data));
    })
    .then(function(data) {
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(draw3(data));
    });
```

The following are in my header:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>    
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.1.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.1.2/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
```

*Update*

If I add `return new Promise` to the draw functions then I am able to execute it in the right order, but the data is not passed from #3 to #4 now.

```
function draw1() {
    return new Promise (function (resolve,reject){
        var db = initFirebase();
        getFirebaseData(db).then(data => {
            console.log("#2: Draw 1 Data: ", data);
            resolve(data)
            return data;
        });
}
        
function draw2(data) {
    return new Promise (function (resolve,reject){
        console.log("#3: Draw 2 Data: ", data);
        resolve(data);
        return data;
    });
}

function draw3(data) {
    return new Promise (function (resolve,reject){
        console.log("#4: Draw 3 Data: ", data);
        resolve(data);
        return data;
    });
}
```

Comment: `new Promise` is an anti-pattern here, since `then` already returns a promise that you can return.  It adds nothing except unnecessary code.

Comment: Without the `new Promise` I do not get the right order nor do I get the data passed from #2 to #3. Other suggestions?

Comment: You say that `draw2` and `draw3` should "reuse the same data". Why have them as separate functions?

Comment: You only need one Google callback per page load, not per chart drawn...

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52003664/5090771)...

Comment: @JackA. In order to do update a live chart, it is required to have a single call for each chart: 



https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_multiple_charts

Answer (score 0):

There's an error with your usage of `setOnLoadCallback`. As mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#load-settings) the purpose of `setOnLoadCallback` is to call a function that will be executed once the libraries have been loaded, **it's not required** to use it every time you draw a graph, instead use the [`draw`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_draw_chart#draw-your-chart) method for creating the graph.

My suggestion is to create a function that gathers all the data from Firestore, which will be called from the `setOnLoadCallback`, and once the data has been gathered call the subsequent draw2, draw3 functions from there.

A revamp of your code could be something like:

```
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(draw1);

function draw1() {
    var db = initFirebase();
    getFirebaseData(db).then(data => {
        console.log("#2: Draw 1 Data: ", data);
        let dataFromDB  = modifyDataFromDB(data); //Here you should modify your data to use on the addRows method in the next two functions
        draw2(data);
        draw3(data);
    }); 
}

function draw2(dataFromDB) {
      //Create here your graph 2 with the data sent use the draw method
      data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('string', 'Column1');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Column2');
      data.addRows(dataFromDB); //I'm assuming here that the data from Firestore has already the format required

      var options = {
        'title': 'Graph Title',
        'width': 400,
        'height': 300
      };

      chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', selectHandler);
      chart.draw(data, options);
}

function draw3(dataFromDB){
     //Create here your graph 3 with the data sent use the draw method
}
```

The code on the `draw2` function is just an example of how it would look a function that creates a graph so you can understand a little bit better what goes there.

Comment: This is a good idea, but I want to have something more generic and flexible for easy extension and modification.

Comment: @KingsInnerSoul This answer is correct. The only realistic opportunity for making it more "generic and flexible" would be to use an array of "draw" methods in `draw` rather than the hard-coded calls to `draw2` and `draw3`. One other note: the names `draw1`, `draw2` and `draw3` should be improved. The first one doesn't actually draw anything. It should be named to reflect its actual use; something like `onChartsLoaded`. Likewise the `draw2` and `draw3` functions should be named to reflect what they actually do. They should be named to describe the chart that they draw.